# How can I keep the timer running while processing other things

Tags: c#, multithreading, selenium, timer, multiprocessing

I have a timer count down in 60s and a task for checking if an element does exit on webpage (waituntil 60s). The issue is when I click on the button to start. The timer doesn't start until the web driver throw a timeout exception. I have no idea why it runs the try-catch block before the timer does.

My question is how can I make the timer and try-catch block work at the same time. And if an exception is thrown, the timer stops.

Any idea? I appreciate your help.
Thanks.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter--;
        if (counter == 0)
            timer1.Stop();
        txtTimer.Text = counter.ToString();
    }


private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int counter = 60;
        timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Interval = 1000; // 1 second
        timer1.Start();
        txtTimer.Text = counter.ToString();

        // Check if user is already logged in. If not => exit
        try
        {
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("logout"));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Please login first.");
            return;
        }
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Why can't you use `wait.Until` (explicit wait, explained here: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) instead, e.g. `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
    {
        return d.FindElement(By.Id("logout"));
    });`?

Comment: @KirilS. Because I want to show the countdown on the textbox txtTimer. I already set 60s timeout for the web driver.

Comment: oh, so you want it to run asynchronously? I think you need to use something like this then: https://blogs.infosupport.com/c-5-0-async-explained-as-simple-as-possible/ (i.e. selenium task on background, UI "await"-ing and counting down on foreground)

Answer (score 0):

Its not running the try catch before the timer code, the timer is running in the same thread as the selenium code, so when it hits the try catch, FindElement holds the thread based on some implicit wait time caked into selenium.

You need to use a multithreaded timer such as the one in `System.Timers` or `System.Threading.Timer`.